# Set up embedded jetty with document root

Tags: java, servlets, webserver, embedded-jetty

If I enter http://example.com/index.html in my browser, jetty should look in a specified dir for the file index.html.

How can I achieve this with embedded jetty?

This is my code to start jetty:

```
InetSocketAddress socketAddress =InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved("0.0.0.0", 80);
Server server = new Server(socketAddress);
server.start();
server.join();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a good description at http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty

```
public class FileServer{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        Server server = new Server();
        SelectChannelConnector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
        connector.setPort(8080);
        server.addConnector(connector);

        ResourceHandler resource_handler = new ResourceHandler();
        resource_handler.setDirectoriesListed(true);
        resource_handler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{ "index.html" });

        resource_handler.setResourceBase(".");

        HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
        handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { resource_handler, new DefaultHandler() });
        server.setHandler(handlers);

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: This was a great help, but I ran into a bit of trouble trying to get '/' to route to the second handler. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766477/getting-a-403-on-root-requests-when-using-a-resourcehandler-and-custom-handler-i) helped for that.