# Jetty to forward specific request to only a single path

Tags: redirect, jetty

How would I setup Jetty to forward only a specific parent path to a directory? For example when the user requests: localhost/ it should go to localhost/CorrectDirectory. Any requests such as localhost/AnotherDirectory is correct?

The documentation on the [RewriteHandler gives](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-6/apidocs/org/mortbay/jetty/handler/RewriteHandler.html):

```
 <Set name="handler">
   <New id="Handlers" class="org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RewriteHandler">
     <Set name="rewriteRequestURI">false</Set>
     <Set name="rewritePathInfo">false</Set>
     <Set name="originalPathAttribute">requestedPath</Set>
     <Call name="addRewriteRule"><Arg>/other/*</Arg><Arg>/test</Arg></Call>
     <Call name="addRewriteRule"><Arg>/test/*</Arg><Arg></Arg></Call>
     <Call name="addRewriteRule"><Arg>/*</Arg><Arg>/test</Arg></Call>
     <Set name="handler">
```

From the looks of it, if I attempted to put in a rewrite rule for localhost/ I'd have to name every single subdirectory to prevent a direct from say localhost/DirectoryTwo to localhost/CorrectDirectory/DirectoryTwo (which would be incorrect).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got you question right, I assume it was something like:

> I want to redirect "/" but only "/" not "/someting" to "/somedestination"

Have a look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25405898/3489108

You can achieve the desired outcome by using a RewriteRegexRule. The regex "^/$" matches the beginning of the string (^), the exact path (/) and the end of the string ($). This ensures, that only the exact path is matched.

I am using jetty 9 embedded and setup my redirects in code, so I cannot help with figuring out, how you set this up "the config way".